# Junit 5 + Mockito in every method in AuthorServicetest return NullPointerException from Modelmapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

when I execute the test method this happened:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.bookstore.com.ConfigPackage.ModelMappers.authorToDto(com.bookstore.com.domain.author.Author)" because "this.modelMapper" is null
at com.bookstore.com.services.authorService.AuthorService.fetchById(AuthorService.java:47)
at com.bookstore.com.serviceLevelTest.AuthorServiceTest.isFetchAuthorByIdValid(AuthorServiceTest.java:89)
```

this is service method in Author service class:

```
 public AuthorDto fetchById(Long id){

        try {
            Optional<Author> author = authorRepository.fetchById(id);
            if (author.isEmpty()){
                logger.info("author is not exist");
            }
            logger.info("start converting.... and show author before convert : " + author.get());
            AuthorDto authorDto = modelMapper.authorToDto(author.get());
            logger.info("after converted DTO: " + authorDto);
            return authorDto;
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            logger.error("error happen");

            throw  new RuntimeException("Something went wrong! "+ e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

this is authorServiceTest Class and method that produce the error above:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AuthorServiceTest {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorService.class);
    @Mock
    AuthorRepository authorRepository;
    @Mock
    ModelMappers modelMappers;
    @InjectMocks
    AuthorService authorService;

    @Test
    void isFetchAuthorByIdValid(){
        Author author = new Author(1L,"Jack","SSM","Mars");
        Mockito.when(authorRepository.fetchById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(author));

        AuthorDto authorDto = new AuthorDto();
        authorDto.setAuthorId(author.getAuthorId());
        authorDto.setFirstName(author.getFirstName());
        authorDto.setLastName(author.getLastName());
        authorDto.setNation(author.getNation());
        Mockito.when(modelMappers.authorToDto(author)).thenReturn(authorDto);
        AuthorDto authorDtoResult = authorService.fetchById(1L);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(authorDtoResult);
    }
}
```

I do a similar code to my book service test and every method worked, I have tested with PostMan this method is working fine, so I think it should be inside the test class itself, If anyone has a solution please help me solve this I'm a newbie in this career and I still have to keep learn a lot, thanks in advance

Comment: Please post AuthorService constructor.

Comment: hello I saw your comment, then I do recheck my authorService contructor so I have'nt inject modelmapper fied in contructor that's why it got nullexception. Thank you so much Lesiak

Comment: Please delete the question if it was caused by a typo or not reproducible